# Language acceptance by DFA

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

I have some questions regarding acceptance of a language by DFA

1. Whether more that one dfa accept a language
2. Whether a dfa can accept more than one language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand Luke's answer for your second question:

If you fix a DFA (call it $D$), then there are strings that it accepts, let's call the set of those strings $ACC_D$, and strings which it rejects (which we can call $REJ_D$). Each input string is either accepted or rejected, then it is either in $ACC_D$ or otherwise, it is in $REJ_D$. $$ACC_D \cup REJ_D = \Sigma^*, \quad \text{and} \quad ACC_D \cap REJ_D = \emptyset.$$

The set $ACC_D$ is in fact the "language" that the DFA accepts. So it is clear that there can be only one such language that $D$ accepts. It is the "Largest" such set, since all the strings which are not there must be in $REJ_D$, ie., they are rejected by the DFA.

Comment: What if that DFA accepts the language and some more?

Comment: **anything** it accepts is **defined** to be the language..

Comment: So is it possible for my DFA to have two final states and accepts two set of languages

Comment: Good question. You can ask what is the language accepted **per final state**. However, the common definition talks about being accepted by *any one* of the final states, with no distinction between them. So the language of the DFA is the union of all the sets that are being accepted by some final state.

Comment: If i have a DFA like that (with two final states) can I say that this DFA accepts the first language? In that case my DFA accepts more than one language since it accepts the second language also since it has two final states. I am confused with this

Comment: there are acceptable "standard" definitions. You can say that **restricted to one final state** the accepted language is $L_1$. The language accepted when restricted to only the second final state is $L_2$. **BUT**, when you talk to other people, the phrase "The language accepted by the DFA" means only one thing - strings that are accepted by **any** of the final states, in this case, $L_1 \cup L_2$. If you are still confused, please use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) to ask clarifications.

Comment: @user5507 The language of a DFA is DEFINED as the union of all the words which halt in accept state. I.e in your case, the defined language = {what you feel as language for state1} ∪ {what you feel as language for state2}. In short, the way you see the definition of language is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, there can be many DFAs for a language. Many will be silly though, one way to get another is to add unreachable states to any DFA for the language). It is also possible to have more than one sensible DFA:

   [image: Two equivalent DFAs both accepting (a|b)*; the obvious single state DFA with a self loop, and a two state DFA where both states accept.]

   These two DFAs both accept $\{a,b\}^{\ast}$.
2. On the other hand each DFA accepts *exactly* one language (i.e. no DFA accepts zero languages, or two or more languages) .